# How to add tuples and print them out?

Tags: python, tuples, concatenation

How would you implement the addition of tuples so that for every incorrect answer, it adds the answers to the tuple and prints them out for the user to check and see their previous guesses? I attempted multiple things, but they only served to replace the word within the tuple.

```
import random    

words = ("blueberries", "intelligence", "reactor", "thorns", "nightmare",
         "scars", "metal", "coronavirus", "industries", "heart", "workshop",
         "assistant", "bots")

variable = random.choice(words)    
beg = variable[:1]    
end = variable[-1:]    
length = len(variable)

name = input("Hello USER. Please input your name into the console.")

print("Hello " + name + ". Today, we will be playing a word guessing game. I will be giving you the first and last letter along with the length of the word. You must guess what the word is based on these clues.")

print("1st Letter: " + beg)
print("Last Letter: " + end)
print("Length of word: " + str(length))

guess = input("What is your guess?")

while variable != guess:
    if guess != variable:
        guess = input("Your answer is incorrect. Please try again.")
    elif guess == variable:
        break

print("Congratulations, you have guessed correctly.")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add"? What are the multiple things you attempted? Please show a complete example of exactly what the input might be and exactly what output you expect as a result.

Comment: you can create a list, and do a li.append(guess) to this list. A list is created with : li = [], or li = list().

Comment: `beg = variable[0]; end = variable[-1]` would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a `list` is a better choice. Because tuples are immutable. That means for adding an item to a tuple, you should create a new tuple. But lists are more dynamic and you can add items to the lists simpler and better.
So you can just use the following code:

```
previous_choices = []
# Other codes
    if guess != variable:
        previous_choices.append(guess)    
        print(previous_choices)
```

But if you want to use tuples for some reasons, you can use the following code:

```
previous_choices = tuple()
# Other codes
    if guess != variable:
        previous_choices += (guess,)  # In fact, every time a new tuple creates here.  
        print(previous_choices)
```

Also, I think it's better to change the way you are getting the first and last characters. You can simply use `variable[0]` for your `beg` variable and `variable[-1]` for your `end` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add the wrong guess but what you need is you need to concatenate them. And for that I initialised a list and then appending the wrong guesses in that list since tuples are immutable. However if you need the results in tuple then in the end you can convert the list in tuple. I have done few changes in the code. please check it.

```
words = ("blueberries", "intelligence", "reactor", "thorns", "nightmare", "scars", "metal", "coronavirus", "industries", "heart", "workshop", "assistant", "bots")

import random

variable = random.choice(words)

beg = variable[:1]

end = variable[-1:]

length = len(variable)

name = input("Hello USER. Please input your name into the console.")

print("Hello " + name + ". Today, we will be playing a word guessing game. I will be giving you the first and last letter along with the length of the word. You must guess what the word is based on these clues.")

print("1st Letter: " + beg)

print("Last Letter: " + end)

print("Length of word: " + str(length))

guess = input("What is your guess?")
wrong_guess=[]
while variable != guess:
  if guess != variable:
    wrong_guess.append(guess)
    guess = input("Your answer is incorrect. Please try again.")
    print("wrong guesses till now are:",wrong_guess)
  elif guess == variable:
    break

print("Congratulations, you have guessed correctly.")
```